# Jodatime Period produces same output for 2 different start dates and same end date

Tags: jodatime

Please help me understand why does the code below:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Period;
import org.joda.time.PeriodType;
import org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormat;

public class TimeTestFail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTime jdEnd = new DateTime(2014, 5, 1, 0, 0);

        DateTime jdStart1 = new DateTime(2013, 5, 31, 0, 0);

        Period pmd = new Period(jdStart1, jdEnd, PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime());

        // prints "period for jdStart1 = 11 months and 1 day"
        System.out.println("period for jdStart1 = " + pmd.toString(PeriodFormat.getDefault()));

        DateTime jdStart2 = new DateTime(2013, 5, 30, 0, 0);
        Period pmd2 = new Period(jdStart2, jdEnd, PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime());


        // prints "period for jdStart2 = 11 months and 1 day" (same thing as for the other date!)
        System.out.println("period for jdStart2 = " + pmd2.toString(PeriodFormat.getDefault()));

    }

}
```

produce the same period output (11 months and 1 day). As you can see I'm computing the period twice:

```
2013-05-31   -----   2014-05-01
```

and

```
2013-05-30   -----   2014-05-01
```

In both cases it produces 11 months and 1 day, this is the full output

```
period for jdStart1 = 11 months and 1 day
period for jdStart2 = 11 months and 1 day
```

I'm using jodatime 2.9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question:**

"Please help me understand why does the code ..."

**Answer:**

Just **add 11 months and then one day (in this order) to the start date**, and you will observe the same end date.

**Case a:** After having added 11 months to 2013-05-30 you are on the date 2014-04-30. Then adding one day trivially yields 2014-05-01.

**Case b:** After having added 11 months to 2013-05-31 you are on the virtual date 2014-04-31 which does not exist and will be reduced to last valid date 2014-04-30. Then adding one day again yields 2014-05-01. The behaviour of how months are added is well [documented](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#plusMonths-int-).